# How do I restart on a new island in Battle Islands on PS4?

Tags: battle-islands

I upgraded my command center way too early and now I have people attacking me nonstop. I have no good forces leveled up to defend or fight back.  I see many ways to restart on tablets and PC, but nothing about people who play on PS4.

I went to the obvious place in settings -> application saved data management, but it is not listed there at all. Nothing else under settings seems to be relevant to this game.

I want to try again and focus on leveling up the more important stuff before I get the command center too high where I am a non-stop target. If there is any way I can begin again on the PS4 without making a whole new PS4 account that would be nice.